# Is it a bad practice to have a class with a namespace that goes "out" of it's project name?

Tags: c#, naming, namespace

I have a solution with multiple projects, lets suppose there's one project with the name `Company.Name.Foo.Bar`.

If I declare a class inside the project `Company.Name.Foo.Bar` but with a namespace `Company.Name.BlaBla`, would that be a bad practice?

The reason why I want to declare a class with a namespace that goes outside of it's project is to avoid/minimize naming conflict problems, like adding a bunch of alias or changing the name of a class to something different that it really means.

Comment: What kind of a conflict would you be having by using the _actual_ project space in the namespace? Do you have other projects using the same namespace? Because _that_ would be the issue, rather than you staying within your current project's namespace.

Comment: @Flater I have a class that have the same name as the end of a namespace. e.g. class Foo and the namespace is Company.Project.Name.Foo

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem. You're now talking about an issue that is completely unmentioned in your question, and you're only focusing on the solution that you've managed to come up with rather than see if other and better solutions exist. I have voted to close this question but I will support reopening it when it's no longer an XY problem.

Comment: @Flater I understand your point, you are correct. But if I explain my problem, it will be a question for Stack Overflow, not this stack